# Movie with a hand which grants 5 wishes, and each wish closes a finger on the hand

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am trying to remember a film I watched probably 10-15 years ago but the film was likely older than that. It may have been set in New York.

There was a hand with out stretched fingers and each finger represented a wish. If I remember correctly, the main character first wishes for unlimited beer and whenever he closes his fridge the amount of beer inside multiplies.

He then wishes for money which leads to him having stolen cash and running away from the police. Sadly that is all I can remember from it.

Comment: probably found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monkey%27s_Paw or here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adaptations_of_The_Monkey%27s_Paw - the Simpson's version in "Treehouse of Horror II" is notable ;)

Comment: Didn’t the monkeys paw close fingers for each wish? Never saw a movie version of it but I think that’s in the story

Comment: @ToddWilcox No, in the original story, the paw twitches every time it grants a wish, but the Simpsons version is the one where it was holding up three fingers and put one down for each wish.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym Three rather than five of course because characters on the Simpsons (apparently including dead monkeys) have only 3 fingers and a thumb, and I guess the thumb doesn't count.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Could this be the first part of the five-part miniseries, ***[The 10th Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_10th_Kingdom)*** (2000)...?

> *The 10th Kingdom* is an American fairytale fantasy miniseries written by Simon Moore and produced by Britain's Carnival Films, Germany's Babelsberg Film und Fernsehen, and the US's Hallmark Entertainment. It depicts the adventures of a young woman and her father after they are transported from **New York City,** through a magical mirror, into a parallel world of fairy tales.
>
> The miniseries was initially broadcast over five nights in two-hour episodes on NBC, beginning February 27, 2000. It won an Emmy Award for Outstanding Main Title Design in 2000. The premiere had over 14.04 million viewers.

It's not a perfect match by any means, as a man -- the janitor of an apartment building -- is given a *magic bean* (rather than a hand) that grants him *six* wishes (rather than five).

However, the story is mostly set in New York, and the man does wish for a never-ending supply of beer, with the number of beers in his fridge doubling each time he closes and opens the door.

He later wishes for a million dollars, and a bag full of money stolen during a bank robbery appears outside his front door. The police show up a few minutes later and arrest him.

While he's being driven to the station, the man wishes he could escape from the police car, and subsequently ends up running from the police on foot through Central Park.

You can view the scene where he wishes for the beer at the 37:34 mark in the video below. He wishes for the money at the 44:37 mark. The police show up at the 48:10 mark. And he wishes to escape the police car shortly after the 52:17 mark.

Comment: This was it! Thank you so much!